# Update value as null for column having same value for multiple rows sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table data is like

```
+------+---------------+-----
| item | MFGPN         |value |
+------+---------------+-----
| 1    | Z363700Z01    |100   |
+------+---------------+-----
| 2    | Z363700Z01    |200   |
+------+---------------+-----
| 3    | 0119-960-1    |200   |
+------+---------------+-----
| 4    | 445-3-1234    |100   |
+------+---------------+-----
```

I have to check whether for different ids we have same MFGPN .In this case for id 1 and 2 we have same MFGPN .

How can we set some rank for these cases and for id 1 and 2 rank should be same?

Now for same rank for id 1 and 2 instead of some data in column Value I need to update null

The data should look like:

```
+------+---------------+-----
| item | MFGPN         |value |rank
+------+---------------+-----
| 1    | Z363700Z01    |null  |1
+------+---------------+-----
| 2    | Z363700Z01    |null  |1
+------+---------------+-----
| 3    | 0119-960-1    |200   |2
+------+---------------+-----
| 4    | 445-3-1234    |100   |3
+------+---------------+-----
```

Comment: I don't understand the second piece - "Now for same rank for id 1 and 2 instead of some data in column Value I need to update null" Does that mean that records which have a non-unique mgfpn should have null for value?

Comment: first of all there will be values for each record but if anytime we have same mfgpn i have to update the values to null so in this case item 1 and 2 have same mfgpn then i have to update their values to null from 100 and 200 respectively so first 2 records will have null value since they have same mfgpn

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()` and a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by mfgpn) = 1 then value end) as new_value,
       dense_rank() over (order by mfgpn) as rank
from t;
```

Note:  This assigns a ranking, but the highest ranking is based on alphabetic ordering rather than the number of duplicates or the item ids.

If you just want to update the values:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when count(*) over (partition by mfgpn) = 1 then value end) as new_value
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = new_value
    where value <> new_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c9d57/3). (I am assuming the table name is `items`.)

If you are just trying to clear the value for duplicate `MFGPN` then you can do something like:

```
-- If you just want to update the value for duplicates
UPDATE  items
SET     value = NULL
WHERE   MFGPN IN (
            SELECT  MFGPN
            FROM    items
            GROUP BY MFGPN
            HAVING  COUNT(item) > 1
        );
```

However, I'm not exactly sure what the purpose is, so here is a query to help debug the data:

```
-- Subquery with MIN/MAX/COUNT for debugging purposes
SELECT  t.*
    ,   u.*
FROM items t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  t.MFGPN
            ,   MIN(t.item)   AS min_item
            ,   MAX(t.item)   AS max_item
            ,   COUNT(t.item) AS count_item
            ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.MFGPN) AS rnum_item
        FROM    items t
        GROUP BY t.MFGPN
    ) u ON t.MFGPN = u.MFGPN;

-- Results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1740d0/1/1
| item |      MFGPN | value |      MFGPN | min_item | max_item | count_item | rnum_item |
|------|------------|-------|------------|----------|----------|------------|-----------|
|    3 | 0119-960-1 |   200 | 0119-960-1 |        3 |        3 |          1 |         1 |
|    4 | 445-3-1234 |   100 | 445-3-1234 |        4 |        4 |          1 |         2 |
|    1 | Z363700Z01 |   100 | Z363700Z01 |        1 |        2 |          2 |         3 |
|    2 | Z363700Z01 |   200 | Z363700Z01 |        1 |        2 |          2 |         3 |
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle Schema (for testing and complete example):

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    item    int             PRIMARY KEY,
    MFGPN   varchar(256)    NOT NULL,
    value   varchar(64)
);

INSERT items
VALUES
        (1, 'Z363700Z01', '100')
    ,   (2, 'Z363700Z01', '200')
    ,   (3, '0119-960-1', '200')
    ,   (4, '445-3-1234', '100')
```